# NLog Conditional Variable Value

Tags: conditional-statements, nlog

In NLog, is there a way to have a variable with a conditional value?  I've seen this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Layout-Renderer and tried the following:

```xml
<variable name="EnvironmentString" value="${when:when='${IsProd}' == 'true':Prod:else:Stage}"/>
```

but the value is just returned as a literal; the logic is not being processed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

1) Change the syntax to this:

```
${when:when='${var:IsProd}'=='true':inner=Prod:else=Stage}
```

Note:

:else= rather than :else:

:inner=

var:IsProd (assuming IsProd is another variable)

2) Move the whole conditional to the final Layout

```
<target ... layout="other stuff|${when:when='${var:IsProd}'=='true':inner=Prod:else=Stage}|other stuff" ... />
```

I've not managed to get conditionals working in variables. Perhaps someone else could say why.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

But it depends how the variable is used.

If you use:

```
${EnvironmentString}
```

Then it's evaluated when loading the configuration, and so you could use it for all parameters.

To evaluate it dynamically, use

```
${var:EnvironmentString}
```

But please note that `${var}` only works if the parameter of the Target/Layout is of type `Layout`